# How to convert a statement into PreparedStatement in JAVA

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

i like to change the old one into new and my old sql query its in statement and i like to change into prepared statement . how could i change ? 
for example :

*

```
strSql = "SELECT Id as GroupId, Name,Description FROM Groupcodes WHERE deleteFlag=0 and GroupType = '" + StrGroupType +  "' ";
 if(strSearchBy.length() > 0 && strSearchText.length() > 0)
      {
          if(strSearchOption.equalsIgnoreCase("Starts With")) {
              strSql += " AND " + strSearchBy + " LIKE '" + strSearchText + "%' ";
          }
          else if(strSearchOption.equalsIgnoreCase("Contains")){
              strSql += " AND " + strSearchBy + " LIKE '%" + strSearchText + "%'" ;
          } 
      }   

      strSql += " ORDER BY Name ASC";

      if( nCounter > 0 )  {   
          strSql += " LIMIT " + (nCounter - 1) + ", " + nMaxCount;
      }
```

*

once you teach for this example then i will do for upcoming codes .

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this:

```
PreparedStatement mStatement = getDBTransaction().createPreparedStatement("select * from test_table where user_id = ?", 0);
    mStatement.setString(1, "4913");
    ResultSet rs = mStatement.executeQuery();
```

The '?' character parametizes the query and later u set its value using setString. Note in the setstring function the first parameter is indicated by index 1 (not 0 ). Also note u dont need ' ' if your where condition is comparing varchars

Comment: okay thanks . i will change GroupType = ? like this and strSearchby is an column name and how to use ? for that .

Comment: same thing something like: PreparedStatement mStatement = getDBTransaction().createPreparedStatement("select * from test_table where strSearchby = ?", 0);

Comment: yes for that above example and strSearchBy is a string so how to change and grouptype is an column name so we use ? for that but am declare a string so confusing

Comment: ohh i see what youre saying, yeah just do `mStatement.setString(1, strSearchBy);`

Comment: strSql += " AND " + strSearchBy + " LIKE '" + strSearchText + "%' ";   for this strSql how to change into prepared statement